# Need help codeigniter restclient with node server

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, rest

I have a rest client in codeigniter and a server side in node.
[The source link for codeigniter rest client](http://getsparks.org/packages/restclient/versions/HEAD/show)
My client side rest controller looks like this

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
    $this->load->library('rest');
    $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://localhost:3000/'));
  }

 public function post() {
   $param = array(
     'var1'=>1,
     'var2'=>2
   );

  $this->rest->format("application/json");
  $this->rest->post("/", $param);
  var_dump($this->rest->get("/"));
 }
}
```

And on the server side I have

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var query1 = req.body.var1;
  var query2 = req.body.var2;

 res.json({result: parseInt(query1) + parseInt(query2)});
});
app.listen(port);
```

but when I am requestion `localhost/welcome/post`
   I am getting the resposne

```
string(14) "Cannot GET // "
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the post function in the CI controller to

```
 public function post() {
   $param = array(
     'var1'=>1,
     'var2'=>2
   );

  $this->rest->format("application/json");
  //since the server url is allready mentioned as http://localhost:3000/
  // no need to mentin "/" again
  // response should be handled by a variable
  $response = $this->rest->post("", $param);
  var_dump($response);
}
```